# Is there an unresolvable circular reference? while using latest spring boot version 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

I used Springboot version 2.5.3 which works fine. Now, I upgraded the version to [2.7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot), I got the following error when I run bootRun,

**Error on bootRun:**

```
***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************

 

Description:


The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
 

   appConfigAdapter (field com.XXX.XXX.AppInterceptor com.XXX.XXX.AppConfigAdapter.appInterceptor)

      ↓

   appInterceptor (field com.XXX.XXX.XXX.LService com.XXX.XXX.AppInterceptor.lService)

      ↓

   lService defined in com.XXXX.Application

┌─────┐

|  testService (field private com.XXX.XXX.XXX.SchemaService com.XXX.XXX.TestService.schemaService)

↑     ↓

|  schemaService (field private com.XXX.XXX.TestService com.XXX.XXX.XXX.SchemaService.testService)

└─────┘

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Comment: From Spring Boot 2.6.x onwards, Circular References are prohibited by default. You should try and fix the underlying issue instead of adding the property to go back to old defaults.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle do you have a link to this info?

Comment: @florin https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes

Answer (score 1):

you can try either of the following two solutions.

1. Allow circular dependency in resources/application.properties  file. (not
   recommended)

   spring.main.allow-circular-references= true
2. Upgrade Apache Tomcat embedded version to 9.0.64 in pom.xml file.